# How to display a table in a popup box with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have the form below, with 4 comboboxes "Metier" "tache" "tacrification" et "technicien", I select a Metier and a tache, after this I want that a popup box appears and show me a table that contains all the "techniciens" and their "tarification" (of course only the "techniciens" that are related with the "tache" already selected.)

After this I select a "technicien" from that table a now the form is completely filled with the "technicien" and it's "tarification".

[image]

**iterventioncontroller**

```
public function create()

{
$client = client::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
$metiers = metier::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
$technicien = Technicien::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
$tarifications = tarificationtache::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

return view('intervention.create')->with('technicien', $technicien)- 
>with('client',$client)- 
>with('metiers',$metiers)->with('tarifications',$tarifications);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function store(InterventionRequest $request)
 {
$intervention = new Intervention();
$intervention ->date_intervention =$request- 
>input('date_intervention');
$intervention ->description =$request->input('description');
$intervention ->duree_prevu =$request->input('duree_prevu');
 if($request->has('statut')){
$intervention->statut = $request->input('statut');
}else{
       $intervention->statut = 0;
}

$intervention ->technicien_id = $request->input('technicien_id');
$intervention ->client_id = $request->input('client_id');
$intervention ->tarification_id = $request->tarification_id;
$intervention->save();
return redirect('intervention');

}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
 @extends('Layouts/app')
 @extends('Layouts/master')

 @section('content')
 <!--  jQuery -->
 <script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">


var getTachesByMetierUrl = "{{url('/tachesbymetier')}}";
var getAdresseByClientUrl = "{{url('/adressebyclient')}}";
var getTarificationsByTacheUrl = "{{url('/tarificationsbytache')}}";
var getTechniciensByTarificationtacheUrl = " 
{{url('/techniciensbytarificationtache')}}";

//console.log(getMetiersByTechnicienUrl,getTachesByMetierUrl,getTarificationsByTacheUrl);

    function getAdresseByClient(val) {
    if(val.length>0) {
        var client_id = val;
        $.get(getAdresseByClientUrl+'/'+client_id,function(res) {
            var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
            $.each(res.adresses,function(index,item) {
                html+='<option 
    value="'+item.id+'">'+item.code_postal+'</option>';
            });
            $('#adresses').html(html);

        });
    }
    }


function getTachesByMetier(val) {
    if(val.length>0) {
        var metier_id = val;
        $.get(getTachesByMetierUrl+'/'+metier_id,function(res) {
            var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
            $.each(res.taches,function(index,item) {
                html+='<option 
  value="'+item.id+'">'+item.libelle_tache+'</option>';
            });
            $('#taches').html(html);

        });
    }
}
function getTarificationsByTache(val) {

    if(val.length>0) {
        var tache_id = val;
        $.get(getTarificationsByTacheUrl+'/'+tache_id,function(res) {
            var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
            $.each(res.tarifications,function(index,item) {
                html+='<option 
  value="'+item.id+'">'+item.tarif+'</option>';
            });
            $('#tarifications').html(html);

        });
    }
}

function getTechniciensByTarificationtache(val) {
    if(val.length>0) {
        var tarificationtache_id = val;
        $.get(getTechniciensByTarificationtacheUrl+'/'+tarificationtache_id,function(res) {
            var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
            $.each(res.techniciens,function(index,item) {
                html+='<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.id+'</option>';
            });
            $('#techniciens').html(html);

        });
    }
}
```

```
@if(count($errors))
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
            <li>{{$message}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
<div class="container">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <h1>Ajout Intervention</h1>
    <form action=" {{url ('intervention')  }}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="client">Client</label>
            <select onchange="getAdresseByClient(this.value)" 
 name="client_id" id="client" 
 class="form-control">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                @foreach($client as $t)
                    <option value="{{$t->id }}">
                        {{$t->user->nom}}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">date intervention</label>

            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="example-date- 
 input" name 
 ="date_intervention" value="{{old('date_intervention')}}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">description</label>
            <input type="text"  name ="description" class="form- 
 control"value=" 
 {{old('description')}}">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">duree_prevu</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local"  name 
 ="duree_prevu" value=" 
 {{old('duree_prevu')}}">
        </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Metier: </label>
            <select onchange="getTachesByMetier(this.value)" 
style="width: 200px" 
class="productm form-control" id="metiers">
           <option value="">-Select-</option>
                    @foreach($metiers as $t)
                    <option value="{{$t->id }}">
                        {{$t->libelle_metier}}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>tache: </label>
            <select onchange="getTarificationsByTache(this.value)" 
style="width: 200px" 
class="productname form-control" name="tache" id="taches">
            <option value="">-Select-</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>tarification: </label>
            <select 
 onchange="getTechniciensByTarificationtache(this.value)" 
 style="width: 
 200px" class="productname form-control" name="tarificationtache_id" 
 id="tarifications">
            <option value="">-Select-</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>technicien: </label>
                    <select style="width: 200px" class="productname 
 form-control" 
 name="technicien_id" id="techniciens">
                        <option value="">-Select-</option>
                    </select>
                </div>



 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <link 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap- 
datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"> 
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-         
datepicker.js"></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: - it is very simple, attach an event handler to desired fields that you want to show popup on their base, when user select those fields values, than you achieve in two ways, send ajax request before showing a popup or show popup and then send ajax request and then populate table with the help of javascript or jquery on the basis of returned data.

Comment: @MuhammadSadiq Thank you so much, could you explain me with an example so i can use it to do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [bootstrap 4 modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp).