# How to display a table in a popup box?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have the form below, with 4 comboboxes "Metier=profession" "tache=task" "tacrification=pricing" and "technicien=technician", I select a Metier and a tache, after this I want that a popup box appears and show me a table that contains all the "techniciens" and their "tarification" (of course only the "techniciens" that are related with the "tache" already selected).

Please see the second form. After this I select a "technician" from that table a now the form is completely filled with the "technician" and it's "pricing".

[image]

What I'm trying to do:

[image]

**intervention**

```
    Schema::create('interventions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('date_intervention')->nullable();
        $table->string('description');
        $table->dateTime('duree_prevu');
        $table->boolean('statut');
        $table->integer('technicien_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('technicien_id')->references('id')- 
        >on('techniciens');
        $table->integer('tarification_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('tarification_id')->references('id')- 
        >on('tarificationtaches');
        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('Clients');


        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**tarificationtache**

```
Schema::create('tarificationtaches', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->float('tarif', 8,2);
         $table->integer('tache_id')->unsigned();
         $table->foreign('tache_id')->references('id')->on('taches');
         $table->datetime('deleted_at')->nullable();
         $table->timestamps();
          });
```

**Intervention class**

```
class Intervention extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [ ];
protected $guarded = [];

public function avisintervention()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AvisIntervention::class);
}

public function technicien()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(technicien::class);

}

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);

}
 public function tarificationtache()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Tarificationtache','tarification_id');
```

}

**tache class**

```
class tache extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $guarded = [];
 protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function metier()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Metier::class);
}

public function tarificationtache()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tarificationtache::class);
}

}
```

**metier class**

```
class metier extends Model 
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $guarded = [];
 protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
public function taches()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tache::class);
}
public function techniciens()
{
    return $this- 
    >belongsToMany('App\technicien','technicien_zone','metier_id','technicien_id');

}
}
```

**tarificationtache class**

```
class tarificationtache extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $guarded = [];
 protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
public function tache()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tache::class);
}


public function techniciens()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\technicien','technicien_tarificationtache','tarificationtache_id','technicien_id');

}
public function intervention() {
    return $this->hasMany(intervention::class);
}

}
```

**intervention controller**

```
public function create()

{
    $client = client::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $metiers = metier::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $technicien = Technicien::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    $tarifications = tarificationtache::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    return view('intervention.create')->with('technicien', 
$technicien)->with('client',$client)->with('metiers',$metiers)- 
>with('tarifications',$tarifications);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(InterventionRequest $request)
{
    $intervention = new Intervention();

    $intervention ->description =$request->input('description');
    $intervention ->duree_prevu =$request->input('duree_prevu');


    if($request->has('statut')){
    $intervention->statut = $request->input('statut');
    }else{
           $intervention->statut = 0;
    }

    $intervention ->technicien_id = $request->input('technicien_id');
    $intervention ->client_id = $request->input('client_id');
    $intervention ->tarification_id = $request->tarificationtache_id;
    $intervention->save();
    return redirect('intervention');

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this to know how to create a Modal: [Bootstrap Modal W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Next put your table inside this div

```
<div class="modal-body">
    //put your table in here
</div>
```

After populate the table using this Javacript code

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url:your_url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success:function(employee_list){
    $table_body = $("#tbl_body_name");
    $table_body.empty();

    if (employee_list.length > 0) {
        div_no_data.style.display = 'none';
        $.each(employee_list, function (index, value) {
            $table_body.append('<tr class="deselected" onclick="rowSelect(this)">' +
                '<td style="text-align: left;">' + value.technician_id  + '</td>' +
                '<td style="text-align: left;">' + value.tache_id + '</td>' +
                '</tr>');
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Next use this function to get selected row information and set it to your desired dropdown

```
function rowSelect(currentRow){
    //this is the code to set a dropdown menu using jquery
    var technician_id = selectedRow.children[0].innerHTML;
    $("#your_technician_dropdown_menu_id").val(technician_id);
}
```

Comment: @IT2704: are you familiar with "accepting" answers here? It is not mandatory but it is encouraged. If Sakib's answer solved your problem on this page, you can click the tick icon to mark it as helpful to you. You are free to upvote it as well if you thought it was especially good.

Comment: @Sakibabrar Thank you so much. This question contains my create.blade.php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294290/how-to-display-a-table-in-a-popup-box-with-javascript , how i should call it please ?